# PLPGSQL buscar una arreglo en una consulta SQL

Tags: array, busqueda, plpgsql

Hola tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE base.dia_festivo(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(30)
);
```

y cree una función que recibe parámetros

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_ids(p_tipo integer[] ) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE plpgsql  
  AS $$
  DECLARE
     v_resp integer;
   BEGIN
     SELECT count(*) INTO v_resp FROM base.dia_festivo as a WHERE (a.id IN p_tipo);   
     RETURN v_resp ;
  END;
$$;
```

No me funciona, ¿alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LÍNEA 1: ...ECT count(*) FROM base.dia_festivo as a WHERE (a.id IN  $1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está cuando chequeas si el valor de la columna id se encuentra entre los elementos del arreglo p_tipo (`a.id IN p_tipo`).

En [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html) para chequear si un elemento se encuentra presente en un arreglo lo puedes hacer de las siguientes maneras (seguramente habrá otras formas de hacerlo también):

```
--En estos casos de ejemplo chequeo si el valor a.id (columna id de una tabla con alias a) se encuentra presente en el arreglo '{1,2,3}' (ARRAY[1,2,3]):

-- array_position: retorna el indice en el arreglo de la primera ocurrencia del segundo parámetro o nulo si no está presente.
array_position('{1,2,3}', a.id) IS NOT NULL

-- unnest: expande el arreglo en un conjunto de filas.
a.id IN (SELECT unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[]));

-- chequeo si un arreglo (de un elemento: a.id) está contenido en el segundo arreglo.
ARRAY[a.id] <@ '{1,2,3}'

-- agrego el valor a.id a un arreglo vacio y chequeo si ese arreglo (de un elemento) está contenido en el segundo arreglo.
(a.id || '{}'::int[]) <@ '{1,2,3}'
```

De está forma tu función se crea correctamente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_ids(p_tipo integer[] ) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE plpgsql  
  AS $$
  DECLARE
     v_resp integer;
   BEGIN
     SELECT count(*) INTO v_resp FROM dia_festivo AS a WHERE array_position(p_tipo, a.id) IS NOT NULL;   
     RETURN v_resp ;
  END;
$$;
```